# A better solution for excluding code?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Due to requirements changing back and forth, we have some if/else blocks using consts in our code, for exampe:

```
const bool DisplayAverageValues = true;
if(DisplayAverageValue)
{
  // Do this
}
else
{
  // Do that
}
```

Since the requirements might change again, we don't want to remove the currently unused code - it might be needed next week. We also don't want to comment out the unused code, since we want it to be part of any refactoring. It should be ready for compilation at any time by just changing the boolean value.

The problem is that we get warnings for unreachable code, so I was thinking about replacing the standard if/else-block with the preprocessor #if/#else.

```
#define DisplayAverageValues
#if DisplayAverageValue
  // Do this
#else
  // Do that
#endif
```

The problem I'm facing now is that a preprocessor symbol can't be set to false, it can only be defined or undefined. It would be a lot more obvious to change from:

```
#define DisplayAverageValues true
```

to

```
#define DisplayAverageValues false
```

instead of

```
#undef DisplayAverageValues
```

or

```
//#define DisplayAverageValues
```

(which might cause trouble if the same symbol name has been used elsewhere).

Is there a better way?

Comment: The preprocessor option sounds best IMO. Commenting the `define` line isn't too bad. Just be organized as to where you write all `define`s.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem with #define? Looks good IMO.

Comment: The standard approach is to use `#if SYMBOL ... #endif`, and then define (or don't define) `SYMBOL` in your project settings (so there's no commenting involved.)

Comment: I would try to extract these different parts into [strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) that are dynamically loaded based on a configuration setting. That would fully embrace the fast changing requirements and not try to work around them.

Comment: The problem I see is when another developer comes around to change the define, so that the "Do that" block is run instead. It's might not be obvious how to change the line `#define DisplayAverageValues` to make the other block run. The #define's will be placed right before the #if-block.

Comment: Option #2: Nail down requirements *before* coding :) (Oh, and ask for a pony while you're at it.)

Comment: #define-s are just pre-processor, if you need more logic (and I dislike them too, they make for ugly code, though necessary at times) - move it all into some `Configuration` class - and handle it there any way you like (hardcode or else), and you'll void compiler warnings. And since you need it to be more 'flowy', and ready at any time, it smells like config more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some good suggestions in the comments and in the answer by Tigran, but for now I will stay with a simple solution that is still easy to understand. By dropping the symbol name, there is no doubt in how to change the code if needed:

```
#if true
  // Display average values
  ...
#else
  // Do not display average values
  ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor dirrectives are good in case when you have presice slices in your code architecture, when one code has to be compilable and not intersecting with other. In your case, it much seems that you face different *options*, that somehow also may intersect in requirements along code execution flow.

In my opinion, the best way to manage this is define a `Options`, `RuntimeConfigurations`, or whatever else, class that holds all properties which would impact your application runtime behavior, and pass the *instance* (may be also a `Singletone`) of that class along the parts of your application that has to take in consideration different execution options.

Another option as Daniel said, is exracting that code into different modules, plugins if you wish, and load them dynamically. But it may or may not be possible to implement, and by the way, you will need to spend non irrelevant amount of time, generaly, to achieve this level of flexibility, if it wasn't considered before in your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Processor directives seems to be not designed for such cases. From SOLID point of view you should do the following:

1) Create some interface:

```
public interface IDoingSomething {
  void Do();
}
```

2) Create 2 implementations of this interface:

```
public class DoingThis : IDoingSomething {
  public void Do() {
    // Do this
  }
} 

public class DoingThat : IDoingSomething {
  public void Do() {
    // Do that
  }
}
```

3) Somewhere at the application starting point read the config and make decision of which implementation to use:

```
IDoingSomething doerSomething;

if(DisplayAverageValue) {
  doerSomething = new DoingThis();
} else {
  doerSomething = new DoingThat();
}
```

4) Now use you interface object in code to do something:

```
doerSomething.Do();
```

This is kind of **Strategy pattern** that allows you to have multiple implementations, swith between them in just one place and do not require any code change except classes with concrete interface implementation. This is good for code maintenance, scalability etc.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you'll still get a warning for unreachable code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by warning? It is just quick code snippet, just an idea.

Comment: The original poster said: _'The problem is that we get warnings for unreachable code'_. That will still be the case with your solution (because it does not get around `const bool DisplayAverageValues = true`) even if the design is much better.